# how to use the round maths function in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am use the textbox value like `1455.23`, use the round function my output is `0000145523` but customer not enter float values like `1234` my output is `0000123400` pls give me suggestion
**my code is format.cs**

```
public bool formatAmount(float flAmount, out string strOutput)
{
  bool bval = false;
  float rounded = (float)Math.Round(flAmount, 2);
  if(rounded!=null)
  {
    flAmount = flAmount * 100;
    strOutput = Convert.ToString(flAmount);
    bVal = true;
  }

  return bVal;
}
```

In my asp page code like this

```
string ods;
float a = Convert.Todecimal(txtSSA.Text);
string sss = oclsUtility.formatAmount(a, out ods);
```

Comment: What should the output be when a user enters 1234?

Comment: @hmk: Please provide an example of the input string and the required output format.

Comment: Your `if` statement does not make sense: A value of type `float` will never be `null`.

Comment: Your code is total mess and full with errors. You didn't ask any clear question. Please edit your question and try to explain what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you, you need to keep leading 0 if user input is float and if not removes them. You can try this:

```
int number;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(rounded, out number);
if (result)
{
    // Your number will contain the number with no leading 0
}
else
{
    // Then you have a float.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to ignore the multiplication of 100 part in case the fractional value is not there.

So 1234 in your case is essentially 1234.00 and you need to avoid the 00001234`00`

```
float flAmount = 15F;
float rounded = (float)Math.Round(flAmount, 2);
double fractionalval = (rounded - Math.Floor(rounded)) * 100;
if(fractionalval > 0)
   flAmount = flAmount * 100;
```

After this i presume rest might work and pad it to 10 length string.

This would skip the multiplication if there are fractional parts, hope this is what you need else please edit for additional information.